# Método POST em Angular

Tags: angular, http, typescript

Tenho uma simples aplicação em Angular e preciso realizar uma chamada para minha API para obter um *token*. Porém estou enfrentando dificuldades. Vou tentar explicar um pouco sobre meu fluxo.

Criei uma classe de serviço aonde instancio ela apenas uma vez para guardar um Token. Esse token vem de uma API, porém essa API não me retorna um token em todas as chamada, pois esse token tem um tempo de vida de 15min. Quando a API me retorna um token, o mesmo vem nesse formato:

```
{access_token: "32-GaypcnKItxyYBhc9HRINLebbzuoWul9q0zNitHq0ZVIcVGB…AV2LoFg3uoY6xNIMExkKEbGyda_5Z0RXFnKdi6UsBPH5b-Lwa", token_type: "bearer", expires_in: 3599}
```

Caso venha nesse formato, minha intenção é pegar esse token recebido pela a API e guarda-lo dentro da minha classe dita acima.

Caso a API não me retorne um Token, a resposta vem nesse formato:

```
Response {_body: "{"error":"deny","error_description":"permitido som… autenticação por aplicação à cada 15 minuto(s)"}", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, …}
```

Informando pelo _body, um erro descrito: 'permitido som… autenticação por aplicação à cada 15 minuto(s)'.

Caso venha nesse formato, minha intenção é entrar na classe que instanciei de inicio e obter o token que está na classe dita acima.

Quando a API retorna um Token, eu consigo pegar o mesmo. Porém quando não retorna um Token, eu não consigo pegar o token que está guardado na classe.

Alguém poderia por favor me ajudar?
Aqui em baixo o código das tentativas

**Classe de serviço**

```
 ObterToken(): Observable<any> {
  const header = new Headers();
  header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  const bodyOptions = { 
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: 'varejo_user', 
      password: 'w6h5xgtl'
  }
  const body = `grant_type=${bodyOptions.grant_type}&username=${bodyOptions.username}&password=${bodyOptions.password}`;

  return this.http.post(`${ApiDeSegurança}`, body, new RequestOptions({headers: header}))
      .map(response=> response.json());
}

ObtendoToken(): string {
  return this.tokenModel.token;
}

AdicionandoToken(token: string): void {
  this.tokenModel.token = token;
}
```

**Component que executa o método da classe de serviço**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObterToken().subscribe(res => this.token = res);
}
```

---

**Pergunta editada**

Funcionou dessa maneira:

```html
  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObterToken().subscribe( res => { 
            this.apiDeSegurancaService.AdicionandoToken(res.access_token);
        }, error => { 
            this.token = this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObtendoToken();
        });
}
```

Porém, preciso realizar um outro método com esse token, então preciso realizar esse outro método apenas quando essa primeira requisição tiver resposta! Como posso fazer isso?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: por retornar 400 o angular vai tratar como erro, neste caso inves de tratar no subscribe vc tem que usar o operado cathError, https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObterToken().subscribe(
               res => { this.token = res } , error => { this.error = error  } );
} 

você pode receber a tratativa do error adicionando uma sequência da resposta.

Comment: @LucasBrogni, dessa forma consegui obter o token. postei o código do ngOnInit em uma edição da pergunta. Muito obrigado. Porém tenho outra dúvida. Preciso utilizar esse token para realizar outro método, agora GET, passando o token como parâmetro...Descreverei melhor na edição da pergunta. Porém de qualquer forma, agradeço...

Comment: Guilherme, vou colocar minha resposta ali como resposta, se puder marca ela como resposta. Abraços.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode receber a tratativa do error adicionando uma sequência da resposta.

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
   this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObterToken().subscribe(
    res => { 
       this.token = res 
    }, error => {
       this.error = error 
   }); 
}
```

Comment: Você teria alguma ideia sobre a minha segunda dúvida por favor?

Comment: Guilherme, me passa o link que amanhã dou uma olhadinha. Hoje eu estava bem corrido aqui e só consegui entrar algumas vezes.
Assim que eu conseguir te ajudo.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem ela aqui por este tópico :s

Comment: Posso criar uma nova pergunta e te mandar o link?? para poder esclarecer melhor minha dúvida? Agradeço desde já..

Comment: Pode sim @GuilhermeNunes no que eu puder ajudar vou ajudar hehehe, abraços.

Comment: Ai está o link da nova pergunta:     https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306385/vários-requisições-dependentes-no-angular