# Vários requisições dependentes no angular

Tags: angular, http, typescript

Olá, estou fazendo um processo no angular, no método 'ngOnInit()', aonde preciso realizar 3 métodos HTTP, que são assíncronos. um depende da resposta do outro. por exemplo:

1° chamada: obtem um token

2° chamada: só acontecerá depois da 1°, e vai obter a longitude e latitude

3° chamada: vai receber uma lista de objetos, passando como parâmetros o token e as coordenada.

Porém, não sei como realizar esses métodos na ordem, ou seja, esperar a resposta de um para iniciar o outro...

***Código da 1° chamada:***

```html
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObterToken().subscribe(
        res => { 
            this.apiDeSegurancaService.AdicionandoToken(res.access_token); 
        }, 
        error => { 
            console.log(error._body); 
            this.token = this.apiDeSegurancaService.ObtendoToken();
        }
    );
}
```

Agradeço desde já....

Comment: Guilherme agora ficou mais claro para mim. 
Você pode fazer de algumas formas isso. 

Como eu faria: 

Chamaria um dentro do subscribe do outro.

Eu tinha uma situação muito parecida para pegar o estado e cidade ... fiz da seguinte forma: 
         `   this.cidadeService.getByIbge(response.ibge)
              .subscribe(res => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.cliente.cidade = res[0];
                  this.getCidade(this.cliente.cidade.estadoId);
                }, 500)
              }); `
E dentro do meu getCidade eu fazia a chamada para outra api

Comment: Fazendo a chamada sempre dentro do subscribe da requisição anterior você terá certeza que ele só será executado após a resposta da mesma.
Seria possível também fazer com async e await ou ainda o que eu acho mais incorreto mas possível é realizando eventos com o EventEmitter...

Comment: Porém creio que a primeira sugestão que te dei é a mais adequada para a sua necessidade.

Comment: Então, eu não gostaria de fazer dentro do subscribe, pois gostaria de fazer mais desacoplado entende? e eu teria que ficar passando parametro do 1° para o 2°, pois seria o 2° que chamaria o 3° e o 2° não iria utilizar esse parâmetro, iria receber ele então apenas para servir de ponte para o 3°. Entende? rsrs ficou um pouco confuso

Comment: Entendi, entretanto nas 3 formas haveria uma interdependência. 
Caso você utilize o async e await... você teria que fazer a chamada do segundo método dentro do then 
e caso faça com o Event emitter teria que ter um subscribe do evento. 

Uma outra forma de fazer isso seria com o set timeout para só executar após um tempo mas ai dependendo a conexão já não funcionaria.

Comment: Se não for muito incomodo, você poderia montar um exemplo utilizando o Event emitter?

Comment: Tecnicamente você vai criar um objeto  

`Output() changeValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();`

Dentro do subscribe da primeira teria um emit passando o dado que precisaria.

`this.changeValue.emit(fn);`

E debois recuperaria esse dado da seguinte forma: 
`this.changeValue.subscribe( e => { 
     //Do your job
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possivel realizar esse processo utilizando o switchmap, nas primeira chamadas e na ultima utilizar o Subscrible();

Ex:

ChamadaDaAPI1().switchmap(res => ChamadaDaAPI2()).subscrible();